# C: Adding values of a deck of cards using structures

Tags: c, structure

I have been writing a blackjack program using structures for my C class. The structures in my code are based off of what we have written in class. But I can't figure out how to add the values of the cards after they are dealt to the dealer and the user to further progress my program. I have tried incrementing "i" and printing the values, I have also tried using "i + 1".

How can I get this to work?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct card {
    char * face;
    char * suit;
    int value;
    }Card;


void clearBuffer(){
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

int deal(){
    int deck[] ={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11}; 
    return deck[rand() % 13];
}

int check4ace(int * hand){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(hand[i] == 11){
            puts("found 11");
            hand[i] = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void printDeck(Card deck[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i){
        printf("%s of %s\n",deck[i].face,deck[i].suit);
    }
}

Card * dealCard(Card * deck){
    Card * delt = &deck[0];
    return delt;
}

void shuffle(Card deck[]){
    Card temp;
    int rIndex;
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        rIndex = rand() % 52;
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[rIndex];
        deck[rIndex] = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long timenow;
    timenow = time(NULL);
    srand(timenow);
    char hit;
    char game;
    int answer = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    int total = 0;

    Card deck[52];
    char * faces[] =     {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
    char * suits[] = {"Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades"};
    int values[] = {11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10};

    Card * deckIdx = deck;

    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        deck[i].face = faces[i%13];
        deck[i].value = values[i%13];
        deck[i].suit = suits[i/13];
    }

    shuffle(deck);

    Card * cardHand[10];
    Card * dealerHand[10];
    int hand[10];

    while(1){
        printf("Play a game? (y/n)\n");
        scanf("%c",&game);
        shuffle(deck);
        clearBuffer();
        if(game == 'y' || game == 'Y'){
            cardHand[0] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
            cardHand[1] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
            dealerHand[0] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
            dealerHand[1] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
            printf("\nDealer:\nFACE DOWN\n",dealerHand[0]->face, dealerHand[0]->suit);
            printf("%s of %s\n",dealerHand[1]->face, dealerHand[1]->suit);
            printf("You:\n%s of %s\n",cardHand[0]->face, cardHand[0]->suit);
            printf("%s of %s\n",cardHand[1]->face, cardHand[1]->suit);
    }
        else if(game == 'n' || game == 'N'){
            printf("Bye!\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("No valid answer, Bye!\n");
            break;
        }
        while(game == 'y' || game == 'Y'){
            int i = 0;
            printf("\nHit or Stand? (h/s)\n");
            scanf("%c",&hit);
            clearBuffer();
            while(hit == 'h' || hit == 'H'){
                cardHand[i] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
                dealerHand[i] = dealCard(deckIdx++);
                printf("\nDealer:\n%s of %s\n",dealerHand[i]->face, cardHand[i]->suit);
                printf("You:\n%s of %s\n",cardHand[i]->face, cardHand[i]->suit);
                break;
            }
            if(hit == 's' || hit == 'S'){
                printf("You ended with <value>\n");
                printf("Dealer ended with <dealerValue>\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simple warning: you should write `scanf(" %c", ...)` (with a space), or else it will read your enter key as user input

Comment: And now about your question: *" I can't figure out how to add the values of the cards after they are dealt to the dealer and the user"* -> What have you tried? Why did it fail?